# WinRT C# - Change content of main Frame from child Frame

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have one ListView and ContentFrame (Frame Control) inside of my MainPage.xaml.

For example if I Navigate page Content.xaml to this ContentFrame and then I need to call Navigate from his Content.xaml. But Navigate have to change content of main application Frame (it is parental Frame).

How can I do this?

Comment: Share XAML sample you used, for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to your root frame somewhere - e.g. as a static property on the App class and use that to call Navigate(). Alternatively you can walk up the visual or perhaps also logical tree and find the next frame to get the reference.

Comment: and how can Iwalk up logical tree?